# Android Compile time error Archive for required library: 'lib' in project 'AndroidMagickActivity' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Tags: android, eclipse, github

I have spent a half a day trying to resolve this error but I haven't found a solution. Can anyone please tell me how I can fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the red ! symbol in that project. You are missing the library in project. Please go to the project properties and go to "Java Build Path". In the "Library" tab if it is showing the jar file as cross marked, then load the jar file once again. If the jar file is loaded successfully, then go to order and export and tick the jar file you have loaded. clear the project.

Comment: Did you select the jar in "order and export" file?

Comment: yes i have select my both android jars..testing many times with selecting and un selecting but nothing find to how i can solved my issue..

Comment: Which is your target android version

Comment: Please keep taget android version to the latest or atlease 4.2

Comment: my target is 2.2,i have applied the latest version but still got error..i searched internet and apply all possible solutions but still stucke ;(

Comment: I faced the same problem. It is because of keeping the target sdk to the older version. Try cleaning the project and rebuild it. If nothing worked restart eclipse after doing the above process. It worked for me before.

Comment: It should show android 4... in the top of the folder. At worst case, you need to create another same project with target sdk to the above 4. Let me know if that helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

Relaunch Eclipse, if problem still persist then go to Project Properties and set Java Compiler to 1.6, it should help.

Comment: i have relaunch my eclipse at many many times and also set java compiler to 1.6 but nothing happen and still got an errors..

Comment: Which Eclipse version you are using, Helios?? Have you tried deleting/importing your project?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is only one jar file selected in your project->properties->java build path.
I think this link may be useful: https://code.google.com/p/android-python27/issues/detail?id=1